# How can I transform an ellipse into a circle?

Tags: 2d-graphics

I have an ellipse which has -45 degree axis.

How can I transform the ellipse into a circle? Can I use shear transformation along the x/y axis?

[image]

Comment: Do you just require the outcome to be a circle (any size circle), or does the diagram indicate that you require specifically that size circle from that size ellipse?

Comment: The circle size can be arbitrary size. I just want the transformed into complete circle.
thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a shear, or equivalently a rotation by 45, scale along one of the axes, rotate back (which is equivalent to the shear which you are looking for).

EDIT: On second thought, you don't need to even rotate back unless your circle is marked, since a circle is rotation invariant (if the rotation is around its center).